# Left recursion elimination

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm attempting to eliminate left recursion from a CFG by eliminating indirect recursion then direct recursion as this [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlNUU.gif) shows.

I'll be using this grammar:

```
A = A a | A B C | B C | D D
```

When *i = 1*, and *j = 1* we are looking at replacing all productions of the form *A -> A r* with:

A -> δ<sub>1</sub> γ | δ<sub>2</sub> γ | .. | δ<sub>k</sub> γ

So when I look at *A -> A a* which matches, i should replace it with

```
A -> A a a | A B C a a | B C a | D D a
```

which im sure is wrong

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to replace productions when your replacing it with the production itself?

NOTE : Also, I'm only stuck on the first rule so have omitted the others for simplicity

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[UPDATE]Found as close to the original greek symbols as I could. Also, am I perhaps approaching this in the wrong direction. When *i=1* and *j=1*,  A<sub>j</sub> -> A a | A B C | B C | D D, BUT should I be using A<sub>j</sub>  -> B C | D D
If so then I would get:

```
A -> B C A | B C B C | D D A | D D B C | B C | D D
```

As that would then eliminate the recursion in that production. This a better direction?

Comment: When working on grammars, I find it helpful to write out the LR(0) sets. I find these easier to workout than eliminating left recursion, and it is possible to write a recursive ascent parser from them if you want to do your coding by hand.

Answer (score 3):

This is the recipe:

```
A → Aα1 | ... | Aαm | β1 | ... | βn
```

should be transformed to:

```
A → β1 A' | ... | βn A'
A' → α1 A' | ... | αm A' | ε
```

That is:

1. Replace the recursive productions with new productions in which recursion is on the right. Use a new non-terminal symbol for that.
2. Add a production with an empty right side to the new non-terminal.
3. Append the new non-terminal symbol to the right of the non-recursive productions.

For your grammar:

```
A = A a | A B C | B C | D D
```

you would obtain:

```
A  = B C A' | D D A'
A' = a A' | B C A' | ε
```